# How do I go to the bottom of cygwin terminal?

Tags: cygwin

I have a very simple problem.

When running scripts in cygwin I often go higher to see some first results of the script.

The script itself is still running and is giving output too. To get down again, I click with my mouse wheel but this is giving some input and it is possible this is interupting the script.

My question: what is the normal shortkey in cygwin to get to bottom of the terminal without giving input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: there is no such thing as "cygwin terminal". There is the wellknown command line application in windows, cygwin is running in it.

2: You could use the scrollbar on the right. Isn't is okay?

3: There are some alternate command windows tools for windows. Putty has even a command line window mode. I personally use a full-screen mode [mintty](https://code.google.com/mintty), and I call it to use a [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)`-r -d`.

Comment: The scrollbar isn't quite an option since the output is comming way too fast and when it's down there is already new output and I'm not on bottom again.